# Is there a cleaner way to calculate user session length from such an array?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have an array of events where every event has an action (`login`/`logout`) and a timestamp.

```js
const events = [
  { action: 'login', timestamp: 10 },
  { action: 'logout', timestamp: 20 },
  { action: 'login', timestamp: 55 },
  { action: 'logout', timestamp: 65 },
]
```

I am trying to write a function calculating the total user session length which is defined by the difference between a `login` and `logout`. And a `login` always comes before a `logout`.

```js
function getUserSessionLength(events) {
  let userSession = 0
  let lastTimeLogIn = 0
  for (const { action, timestamp } of events) {
    if (action === 'login') lastTimeLogIn = timestamp
    else userSession += timestamp - lastTimeLogIn
  }

  return userSession
}
```

This works but I wonder if there is a simpler or cleaner way to calculate it? Right now I need to use an extra variable to keep track of the last login timestamp while traversing the array.

Comment: Is there a `logout` entry for every `login`?

Comment: How do you know, that the logout, which follows a login, is from the same session? Is there only one possible session at a time? If not, it might be necessary to add a session id or user id to correctly calculate the session length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `login` events are always followed by `logout` events, you can simply subtract the sum of the `login` timestamps from the sum of the `logout` timestamps:

```js
const events = [
  { action: 'logout', timestamp: 3 },
  { action: 'login', timestamp: 10 },
  { action: 'logout', timestamp: 20 },
  { action: 'login', timestamp: 55 },
  { action: 'logout', timestamp: 65 },
  { action: 'login', timestamp: 85 },
]

userSessionLength = events
  // make sure we start with login
  .slice(events.findIndex(e => e.action == 'login'),
         events.length - events.slice(0).reverse().findIndex(e => e.action == 'logout'))
  .reduce((acc, { action, timestamp }) => acc + (action == 'logout' ? timestamp : -timestamp)
, 0)

console.log(userSessionLength)
```

Comment: hey can I ask why what purposes does `.slice` serve here?

Comment: @Joji that's to remove any mismatched `logout` at the beginning or `login` at the end

Comment: If you remove the call to `reduce` you can see what happens to the array from the `slice`

Comment: super cool! I like your answer! thanks so much

Comment: @Joji no worries - I'm glad you found it helpful

Answer (score 1):

If the logins are even indicies and logouts are odd indicies, it looks like you could do:

```js
const events = [
  { action: 'login', timestamp: 10 },
  { action: 'logout', timestamp: 20 },
  { action: 'login', timestamp: 55 },
  { action: 'logout', timestamp: 65 },
]
function getUserSessionLength(events) {
  let userSession = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < events.length; i += 2) {
    userSession += events[i + 1].timestamp - events[i].timestamp;
  }
  return userSession
}
console.log(getUserSessionLength(events));
```

If the final object might not exist (only a `login` but not `logout` has been recorded yet):

```js
const events = [
  { action: 'login', timestamp: 10 },
  { action: 'logout', timestamp: 20 },
  { action: 'login', timestamp: 55 },
]
function getUserSessionLength(events) {
  let userSession = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < events.length - 1; i += 2) {
    userSession += events[i + 1].timestamp - events[i].timestamp;
  }
  return userSession
}
console.log(getUserSessionLength(events));
```

Comment: what if for some reason, there could be `logout` before `login` or no `logout` after `login`?

Comment: Have the loop condition to stop one beforehand (see second snippet)

Comment: thanks! then if for some reason the first event is `logout`, instead of `login` in which case there would be an error right? I wonder how we can prevent such an error?